# How to use git shortlog to aggregate user commit stats over multiple repositories in a single directory?

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-log

I have a directory with a lot of Git repo subdirectories in it and I would like to accumulate information similar to

```
git shortlog -sne --no-merges
```

for all the repos in it sorting the users by all their total commits.

e.g for repo 1:

```
430 Author 1 <author1@email.com>
 20 Author 2 <author2@email.com>
```

e.g for repo 2:

```
123 Author 1 <author1@email.com>
 92 Author 2 <author2@email.com>
```

**total result:**

```
453 Author 1 <author1@email.com>
112 Author 2 <author2@email.com>
```

Is it possible to do that with git built-in tools?

I was able to go outside of the repo folders and run that for a single folder:

```
git -C repoFolder shortlog -sne --no-merges
```

Comment: `awk` is the way, here, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cd` in a loop into every subdirectory and process `git shortlog` output with `awk`:

```
for d in *; do git -C $d shortlog -ens --no-merges; done |
    awk '{name_email=""; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {name_email=name_email " " $i}; count_by_user[name_email]+=$1} END {for (name_email in count_by_user) print count_by_user[name_email], name_email}'
```

The `awk` script explained:

```
name_email="";
```

For every input line: start with empty variable `name_email`.

```
for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {name_email=name_email " " $i};
```

Join all fields starting from 2 space-separated into `name_email`. I.e. combine all name+email fields.

```
count_by_user[name_email]+=$1
```

Create a new associative array `count_by_user` and in every line increase value (default is 0) by the value of the first field (commits count).

```
END {for (name_email in count_by_user) print count_by_user[name_email], name_email}
```

At the end print results: run through `count_by_user` indices (name+email), print the calculated counter, print name+email. Results are printed unsorted. Could be sorted in the very `awk` script or post-processed with `| sort -nr`.

Developed with `gawk` version of `awk`.

Comment: hi! thank you so much! this is very close I am going to try it soon!

Comment: It works great I ran it with `| sort -rn` so it is reversed :) I

Comment: for other readers I ended up using just the email as a key because users were using different first name and last names per pc so I had duplicates. I also added date range:

`for d in *; do (cd $d && exec git shortlog -ens --no-merges --since="01 Jan 2018" --before="01 Jan 2021"); done |     awk '{email=""; email=email " " $NF; count_by_user[email]+=$1} END {for (email in count_by_user) print count_by_user[email], email}' | sort -rn`

Comment: what do you do if a directory is empty? It shows (reading log message from standard input) and won't continue with the shortlog

Comment: @bbotz Try `echo | git shortlog`