# Fastest way to get a unique list of all emails used to push git commits

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

Say I have 30 git repos cloned to my local computer. What I want to do is a find a list of all the email addresses I have used as the git author in those repos. Is there a way to discover which commits in those repos I have made from my local laptop and the email address for those commits?

Basically, I only want to consider the commits that were made from the current machine and find out the email address for the author of those commits.

I believe the way to do it would be to go to each repo and run:

```
git config user.email
```

but that might only be the current email address, not for previous commits.

Comment: "*commits that were made from the current machine*" Git doesn't keep such information so you cannot filter commits by that criteria. After saying that see if the script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59889216/7976758 helps.